# How to get the below password message in catch block laravel

Tags: laravel

How to get the below password mesage in catch block laravel

```
#messages: Illuminate\Support\MessageBag {#1495
      #messages: array:1 [
        "password" => array:1 [
          0 => "The password confirmation does not match."
        ]
      ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did it and it works in the catch block

```
$message = $e->validator->errors()->first('password');
```